# Serving different ad units per URL (DFP)

Tags: ads, google-dfp

(I'm with a website managing their ad inventory.)

How can I serve a specific set of ad units on a specific set of URLs, and different units (sizes) on other pages of my website? (This is in DFP Small Business).

For example, on 95% my URLs, I'm planning on using the right-hand sidebar to accommodate 300x250s, and several 125x125s. On the remaining 5%, I'm looking to deploy 300x600 in the sidebar, effectively taking over the page (and real estate where the 300x250 and 125x125 would exist otherwise.)

Can I programmatically alternate between configurations A & B, through Doubleclick for Publishers (Small Business platform), so that I don't need to request from our dev team commenting out the ad unit scripts from A to enable the substitute 300x600 unit from config B?

Really appreciate any guidance in advance. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I developed a [jquery plugin to work with DFP](https://github.com/coop182/jquery.dfp.js) - this enables targeting per URL.

It would require you to have all of your ad units on each page but using the URL targeting that my plugin enables you could then have only the correct ads filled on each page based on its URL, the other ad units would stay hidden through the `collapseEmptyDivs` setting.